# Index slicing of multidimensional arrays with a list of slices

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, slice

I have a four-dimensional array of image volumes, data, with size `[94, 64, 64, 64]`. The ordering of these images is not in a specific order, so I want to split this array into four different arrays each with pre-selected indexes.

So for example, I know that the "MCI" data takes up volumes (1st dimension) `(17,18,19,38,39)` so I'd like to be able to take all five of these parts out at once into a new array like this:

```
dataMCI = data[(17,18,19,38,39),:,:,:]
```

as I would if say I wanted the third image out:

```
data3 = data[2, :, :, :]
```

But this method doesn't seem to work. It seems like a really easy question but I cannot find a really easy answer without loops. Obviously I cannot do `dataMCI = data[17:39, :, :, :]` as they are not in sequence.

Comment: This `dataMCI = data[(17,18,19,38,39),:,:,:]` or even  `dataMCI = data[(17,18,19,38,39),:]` works for me, returning an array of shape `(5,64,64,64)`.

Comment: What do you mean by 'this method doesn't seem to work'?
Can you show us an example of your input, output, and expected output?